# How to create new json object from a dict in python?

Tags: python, json, object

What is the best way to create a dict, with some attributes, from another dict, in Python?

For example, suppose I have the following dict:

```
dict1 = { "name": "Juan", "lastname": "Gonzalez", "swimming": "yes", "soccer": "no"}
```

I would like to obtain:

```
dict2 = { "name": "Juan", "lastname": "Gonzalez", "hobbies": {"swimming": "yes", "soccer": "no"}}
```

Which I only need to add the "hobbies"

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? The title is about JSON, but the question itself is about transforming the dictionary. Which one is it?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: What can vary? Is the dictionary always in the form `{"name": ..., 'lastname": ..., "swimming": ..., "soccer": ...}` or do you want to extract all keys other than `"name"` and `"lastname"`, or something else?

Comment: Do you want to put all keys in dict1 that are not 'name' or 'lastname' into hobbies?

Comment: @ForceBru You are right I would like to transform the dict1 to dict2..

Comment: @Jasmijn Hey, dict1 has always the same keys and I just want to create the dict2  grouping "soccer", "swimming" in "hobbies"

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @Sri exactly, I am unsure if dict type should work or as list?

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer:

```
dict2 = {"name": dict1["name"], "lastname": dict1["lastname"], hobbies: {"swimming": dict1["swimming"], "soccer": dict1["socccer"]}}
```

A more flexible answer:

```
toplevel_keys = ['name', 'lastname']
hobbies_keys = ['swimming', 'soccer']
dict2 = {key: dict1[key] for key in toplevel_keys}
dict2['hobbies'] = {key: dict1[key] for key in hobbies_keys}
```

Comment: Hello again, what if the dict 2 hat different keys for some persons? what could you recommend me?

Comment: It depends on which keys are different. I can't really help you further without knowing more.